# Deezer Javascript SDK, not getting full song on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, deezer, mobile-browser

I have created a custom player with deezer for my website. Now I am facing an issue in mobile browsers. I'm only getting 30 second preview song in mobile browsers, even if I logged in to my deezer account. But in desktop browsers it is working fine. I have some tiles with playlists assigned to it and clicking on the tiles will load the playlist in my custom player. But for mobile and desktop i'm using different structure for tiles.

Clicking on each tile will pass 4 parameters(playlistId, a color value, playlistDescription and a urlAvatar) everything is loading successfully but only in mobile browsers songs are only for 30 sec, Can anyone help me, I can't post my code here, it is in ES6 and too complicated.

This is how I'm initializing Deezer

```
DZ.init({
    appId  : 'my AppId',
    channelUrl : 'http://localhost/projects/myprojectname/channel.html',
    player : {
        onload : function(response){
            console.log("player successfully loaded");
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Are you using the premium+ account? I was wrong initially and I believe that clause applied to the embed player. The table here: https://developers.deezer.com/guidelines#content-access suggests that for music on demand you should get full tracks.

Comment: I'm using a premium account

Comment: @Yoda : Thanks Bro, I'll check :)

Comment: Actually, developers.deezer.com/guidelines#content-access explains our guidelines for our apps. As you are using our Javacript SDK, the rules that are applied are available here, at the section "FAQ": https://developers.deezer.com/musicplugins/player